# ngPrime table colum selection and extracting data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to select and extract multiple columns of an table.

What would be the best way to do this? Does NGPrime have something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using JSF? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: No, just Angular, NGPrime, HTML, CSS

Answer (score 0):

in the ngprime you have to select he tables by clicking the mouse from top left of the screen with the commands initialized towards the systematic approach of apprehending the situation to analyse the derivatives of the table generation.